# C# Windows Media Player - Class/Constructor Missing?

Tags: c#, axwindowsmediaplayer

I'm attempting to play an mp3 file from a form. I used the following code:

```
WindowsMediaPlayer player = new WindowsMediaPlayer("mp3 file path here");
```

However, the new WindowsMediaPlayer() function says that the class doesn't contain a constructor that accepts an argument. I also read it sometimes doesn't generate the class properly but by deleting the form component and placing it again, it will correct itself. No luck.

Comment: `player.URL` is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a contructor try 
AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer wmp = new AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer();
wmp.URL="some url";